# Problema do barbeiro dorminhoco com semáforos

Tags: c#, multithreading

Achei esse código online enquanto estudava e não consegui entender duas coisas:

1. O que o semáforo "seatBelt" faz?
2. Por que o barbeiro não está verificando a sala de espera após terminar um corte? (Ele vai diretamente para o estado "Descansando")

Muito obrigado!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random Rand = new Random();
    const int MaxCustomers = 3;
    const int NumChairs = 3;
    Semaphore waitingRoom = new Semaphore(NumChairs, NumChairs);
    Semaphore barberChair = new Semaphore(1, 1);
    Semaphore barberSleepChair = new Semaphore(0, 1);
    Semaphore seatBelt = new Semaphore(0, 1);
    bool AllDone = false;
    void Barber()
    {
        while (!AllDone)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Barbeiro dormindo.");
            barberSleepChair.WaitOne();
            if (waitingRoom.ToString() == "3")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Barbeiro tem que cortar.");
                Thread.Sleep(Rand.Next(1, 3) * 1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Barbeiro corta o cabelo.");
                seatBelt.Release();
                Console.WriteLine("Barbeiro checa a sala de espera");  
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Barbeiro dormindo.");
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    void Customer(Object number)
    {
        int Number = (int)number;
        Console.WriteLine("O cliente {0} vai ao salão.", Number);
        Thread.Sleep(Rand.Next(1, 5) * 1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Cliente {0} está no salão.", Number);
        waitingRoom.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("Cliente {0} entra na sala de espera.", Number);
        barberChair.WaitOne();
        waitingRoom.Release();
        Console.WriteLine("O cliente acorda o barbeiro", Number);
        barberSleepChair.Release();
        seatBelt.WaitOne();
        barberChair.Release();
        Console.WriteLine("Cliente {0} sai do salão.", Number);
    }
    Thread BarberThread = new Thread(Barber);
    BarberThread.Start();
    Thread[] Customers = new Thread[MaxCustomers];
    for (int i = 0; i < MaxCustomers; i++)
    {
        Customers[i] = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Customer));
        Customers[i].Start(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MaxCustomers; i++)
    {
        Customers[i].Join();
    }
    AllDone = true;
    barberSleepChair.Release();
    BarberThread.Join();
    Console.WriteLine("Fim do trabalho!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: o que é Semaphore ? ( o que seus parametros de cosntrução significam) ?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veja o que eu entendi do código. O `seatbelt` é um semáforo que sinaliza se a cadeira do barbeiro está disponível para os clientes. Ela começa vazia (0) e quando um cliente acorda o barbeiro, ele senta na cadeira (`seatBelt.WaitOne()`). Quando o barbeiro acaba de fazer a barba, ele libera a cadeira (`seatBelt.Release()`).

Pelo seu código, o barbeiro verifica a sala até `AllDone` for `true`, isto é, até

```
for (int i = 0; i < MaxCustomers; i++)
{
   Customers[i].Join();
}
```

encerrar. Logo, ele deve atender três clientes e depois encerrar o seu trabalho.